# Change the color of a field in maximo

Tags: java, maximo

I am trying to run validate on a field `(SCHEDHLEDFINISH)` in `Maximo 7.5.`
I want to change the color of the textfield to red and possibly display an error icon on that field as well.
Here what I have

```
public void validate() throws MXException, RemoteException
{   
     MboRemote vend = getMboValue().getMbo();
     vend.setValueNull("SCHEDULEDFINISH",11L);
     throw new MXApplicationException("ABC", "abc");
     //Set RED COLOR to field and display error icon
}
```

How is it possible? What property to set for that?

Answer (score 2):

Are you okay with using the application's UI? I don't know if you can add an error icon, but you should be able to change the textfield to red.

[How to change the color of a field using conditional expressions](http://maximodev.blogspot.com/2012/03/change-color-field-conditional.html)

Briefly:

- Define conditional expression
- Configure WOTRACK application to process the conditional expression
- Verify your results

[Exhaustive list of UI properties you can adjust](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Conditionally%20changing%20user%20interface%20properties)